# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError with scrollMe ANGULAR

Tags: angular, scroll

I am using `scrollMe` in my `chatView` template to scroll the chat messages to the most recent one when a conversation is opened.

It works like a charm when I open the conversation the first time. However if I open the same conversation multiple times, I get a `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error regarding `scrollTop`:

`Previous value: 'scrollTop: 1152'. Current value: 'scrollTop: 576'.` for example.

Here is the template:

`aConversationWasOpened` is initialized to 1 when I open the conversation and `messageList` is filled at the same time.

```
<div *ngIf="aConversationWasOpened === 1">
  <div *ngIf="messageList.length > 0; else elseBlock2">
    <div class="card lg scroll" #scrollMe [scrollTop]="scrollMe.scrollHeight" style="background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);">
      <div *ngFor="let message of messageList">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where does the issue come from? Thanks!

Comment: Show `scrollTop` class

Comment: @AdritaSharma I have no class for `scroll` in my component.ts, I am just using [scrollTop] as it is

Comment: What is `[scrollTop]` ?

Comment: An Angular property

Comment: Can u share a stackbiltz for it

Comment: can u use [hidden] instead of  *ngIf

Answer (score 0):

To update the DOM with updated data, Angular provides its own change detector to each component, which is responsible for detecting change and updating the DOM.

Here is the full Article, https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-change-detection-in-angular

```
 constructor(  private changeDetect:ChangeDetectorRef){}

   if (!(this.changeDetect as ViewRef).destroyed) {
                    this.changeDetect.detectChanges()
                    // do other tasks here

                }
```